# Using Photo Stream and ICloud

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream

I am taking py ipad on holiday and plan to take pictures with my Digital camera and at the end of the day transfer the pictures from the memory card to the ipad via a card reader.

1. Will these photos go into the photo stream?
2. If I set up iCloud on my PC, which will be left at home will the pictures be synced to that automatically? In which case the 1000 picture limit wont be an issue?
3. Am I right in understanding that the pictures will lose some resolution when viewed on the ipad but will keep the resolution when viewed on my Windows PC?
4. Does all of the above only work when connected to WiFi?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for using Ask Different. There are four questions in your question. For your question to be more easily searchable and useful for future readers, please edit your question to fit this site's suggested "one question" format. Thanks.

Comment: For #4, **yes** - your personal Photostream (shared Photostreams are different) only works over wifi. I also concur that you should ask at least one new question and consolidate somewhat.

Comment: While this question would benefit from some rephrasing, I don't see it as being overly problematic. The four sub questions all apply to the main topic: Will vacation photos dumped to an iPad be transferred to my home computer via Photostream?

Comment: I'm running out the door but the short answer to the overall question is "yes, this will work" (for a reasonable quantity of photos--per service restrictions). I followed this same procedure last fall Camera > iPad >>Photostream>> Aperture (running on my Mac) and all my photos (Raw, plus processed jpegs) were in the library when I returned home.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, photos imported into an iPad do get shared through Photo Stream. This feature is mentioned in [this Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4858).

---

The 1000 picture limit is a *per hour* limit. [Apple says](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4858) (in the same KB article) that…

> If you exceed one of these limits, your uploads to Photo Stream will be paused temporarily and you may see a notification message on your device. Your uploads will resume automatically once you no longer exceed one of the limits (such as the following hour or day).

In addition to the 1000 picture limit, there are further limits…

> - Uploads to My Photo Stream per day: 10,000 photos
> - Uploads to My Photo Stream per month: 25,000 photos

These limits can not be circumvented (as far as I know) by having your computer constantly sync to Photo Stream.

---

This [Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486) explains Photo Stream resolutions:

> On your Mac or PC, your photos are downloaded and stored in full resolution. On your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple TV, your Photo Stream photos are delivered in a device-optimized resolution that speeds downloads and saves storage space. While actual dimensions will vary, an optimized version of a photo taken by a standard point-and-shoot camera will have a 2048 x 1536 pixel resolution when pushed to your devices. Panoramic photos can be up to 5400 pixels wide.

---

According to the same [Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486) as the previous, yes, Wi-Fi is required for Photo Stream to work (emphasis not mine).

> On an iOS device, new photos you take will be automatically uploaded to your photo stream when you leave the Camera app and are connected to Wi-Fi. **Note:** My Photo Stream does not push photos over cellular connections.

Answer (score -1):

Then again, if you are at all concerned about Apple's cloud services, as any sane person might be, why not sign up for DropBox - a thoroughly reputable, dependable service that is free up to a certain limit. And you can increase your DropBox size by registering friends etc. The iPhone and iPad apps have automatic Camera Upload service (when you have a connection) and installing the Mac desktop application means that those photos--and anything else synced to DropBox is available to any and all of your Macs. I use it for LAN syncing, moving things around my home network, as well.

Just makes sense to me to have real backups of photos somewhere, and on your machine as well. Also, photos are readily shared from DropBox - though you can make as many photostreams as you like, sending them pretty much instantly to anyone with a Mac who accepts the invitation.

Comment: Keep in mind the OP wasn't asking about *whether or not* they should use Photostream, they were asking *how to use* Photostream for their situation. However, DropBox could be a good option for some, and it doesn't hurt to post an alternative.

Comment: Seemed too long for a comment - but was kind of an add-on to OP.

Comment: I understand. (I didn't downvote). I am curious, though, why you would think sane people would avoid Apple's cloud services in preference for a smaller(?) 3rd-party cloud?

Comment: Apple is just not in the cloud business. Not now. Maybe not ever, unless they focus on it. Hell, I think MobileMe worked better, and sure had nicer stuff--albums, cards, sites, iDisk. Different, I know, Apple and the cloud are a running if fond joke on the Mac blogs about now. Read the sad stories on Apple Support - or don't. Where have all my photos gone?! How to explain to noobs, It mostly all Just Works.

Comment: The real confusion, on every level, is whether iCloud is storage or streaming sync. Photostream is a trip, but you've got to know the tricks, and does dear Apple ever give instructions?